# LaTeX Curly Brackets

Tags: brackets

How do I get curly brackets to show in the output file on share latex? I tried putting them in the input file, but they disappear in the output.

Answer (score 5):

Curly braces have special meanings in TeX, e.g. as argument braces or as group. They can be printed via `\{` or `\}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Curly braces: \{ \}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]